# Terminology for an interval of the form $(a-\delta,a]$ or $[a,a+\delta)$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, terminology

An interval that has the form $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ for some $a\in\mathbb R$ and $\delta>0$ is called a *neighbourhood* of $a$. Is there a similar name for a half-open interval taking the form $(a-\delta,a]$, or $[a,a+\delta)$? I have occassionally heard these intervals as being referred to as "left neighbourhoods" and "right neighbourhoods", respectively, but I'm not sure this is standard terminology. Ideally I would like to see a reference.

Intervals of this kind crop up a fair amount in analysis, e.g. in the definition of a one-sided derivative, an inflection point etc., and so it does not seem unreasonable for them to be given a name.

Comment: Left - and right- neighborhoods of $a$.

Comment: [Unilateral neighborhod](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unilateral+neighborhood%22+math&filter=0) is a term I've heard and seen quite often, although a google search turns up far, far fewer hits than I would have guessed. Of course, if you want to specifically specify "left" or "right", then use the appropriate one of those two words. FYI, in older literature the words "backward" and "forward" were sometimes used, especially with unilateral derivatives. Curiously, I get a lot of hits for ["forward derivative"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22forward+derivative%22+math&filter=0).